# Flat HTML files from PHP/MySQL as records are updated

Tags: php, html, mysql, wget

I have only a couple thousand records in a MySQL db that can be called dynamically via php/url params (**page.php?id=123**). I also have a gnarly legacy function that pulls all the info for that page from the db, and generates a flat .html file based on a *title* field for each record. Every time a record is updated, this function is run and the page is regenerated.

It works well enough, but with a major rewrite around the corner and tons of intermingling html/php and hideous conditional logic in said function, I'd like to be able to update the php page (which works perfectly without the function), and then as records are updated in the backend, a simple command is called that hits **page.php?id=updated_id** and spits out an HTML page in the **/pages** directory, for example.

I was thinking about trying wget but before I go trying system stuff in PHP I thought I'd see if anyone has done anything similar?

The goal is, instead of updating this crazy function that writes html every time there is a design change, I can just edit the php file and change the post-update function to point to **page-v1.php**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to go the route of generating the HTML and then returning it. It's a good solution for creating a v.fast site as there's little work done for each user request.

A more normal way of achieving something similar is to add some level of caching either to your application or by putting a reverse proxy (maybe varnish, lighttpd, squid) in front of the web server.

edit: If it's just a case of wanting to request a URL from within another page you can do this with `file_get_contents()` or any other PHP "file" commands if you have url wrappers enabled. If you want a nicer, more configurable HTTP client from within PHP take a look at [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Fair enough - unfortunately, the decision to generate flat html in the first place wasn't mine, nor mine to make. Came from higher up. Appreciate your response though!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something you should be able to use include(); That will drop the nasty file in wherever you want it.

If that does not work and you still want wget style features look at readfile() (which will take a URL as a parameter) or the curl functions.

Comment: Hadn't thought of readfile, looks like I've got a few options here. Thanks for the response!